# Dart/Flutter : Why should we AVOID public late final fields without initializers?

Tags: flutter, dart

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-public-late-final-fields-without-initializers

> AVOID public late final fields without initializers.
>
> Unlike other final fields, a late final field without an initializer
> does define a setter. If that field is public, then the setter is
> public. This is rarely what you want. Fields are usually marked late
> so that they can be initialized internally at some point in the
> instance’s lifetime, often inside the constructor body.
>
> Unless you do want users to call the setter, it’s better to pick one
> of the following solutions:
>
> Don’t use late. Use late, but initialize the late field at its
> declaration. Use late, but make the late field private and define a
> public getter for it.

The above explanation is abstract and I have no concrete image of what kind of risk this rule envisions.

I would be grateful if you could give me a hint as to how to think.

Comment: The quote is a really good explanation. It's hard to give you a better one that isn't either just as abstract or a wild guess. Why not try the other way around... can you try to describe why you would *want* to do this? Then we can tell you what the specific risk with that specific example is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risk is that you accidental try to assign a value twice, which will result in an error.

```
late final String a;

void someMethod() {   
  a = "a";
  a = "b";
}
```

The above code compiles perfectly fine and is valid code because of the `late` but leads to a crash.

As for the suggested solutions

> Don’t use late.

> Use late, but initialize the late field at its declaration.

```
final String a = "b";
// or
late final String a = "b";


void someMethod() {   
  a = "a";
  a = "b";
}
```

This makes it that the above code doesn't even compile, making it sure that the crash doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
 I'm sure you're right.

At first I thought that the three solutions listed in the document were listed as alternatives for the specific situation of application development, "late & final & public & not initialized when declared".

However, in the end, they were not concrete, but rather thought experiments, such as, "This could lead to this, but if we do this, that risk will be eliminated." But it seems to be presented as a thought experiment. There is no particular "late" or "final" restriction or requirement as a premise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Late modifier means a variable's value is not known during declaration but will definitely get initialized and not null when it's accessed.
2. When we declare a variable as final, it means that it will only assigned once. Therefore, all the final fields has to be initialized either at declaration or inside the class constructor.

Given above facts, for one to declare a late final variable as public would probably a mistake. One should either pass the value to final field as class constructor parameter, or declare the late final field as private and initialize it internally.

Let see the example why late final field should not be made public

```dart
class Coffee {
  late final String temperature;   // public field as there's no prefix underscore, e.g. _temperature

  // based on description from the guide, a setter will be created automatically for public late final
  set temperature(String val) => temperature = val;
  
  // again, do you think you would want above? 
  // as it's final field, it means it should only be initialized once! 
  // The creation of the setter for late final (public field) does not make too much sense
  // Therefore usage late final as public field is rarely what you will want

  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I would like to think a little more while looking at your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's true, but I think this advice is to enforce better architecture. If field is final then you can set it value only once and almost always you need to initialize it from within the class it belongs to.
But if setter for final field is public then people might attempt to set it value from elsewhere AFTER it is already initialized, and this will lead to an error.

UPD: two sections above there is this advice, that basically summarizes my point:

> Objects shouldn’t generally expose more state than they need to.

...and setter is not needed after final field has been initialized.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm sure you're right.

One thing I'm curious about is the second solution.
I don't think it is necessary to use the late keyword in the first place if it is initialized at the time of declaration.
Therefore, it may not be appropriate to make it an "alternative to'late & final & public & not initialized'".

Comment: @森口万太郎 using late if you prefer to defer the initialization of the variable only when it's needed/accessed. One useful scenario would be for those expensive computation that you might not want it to take up the processing time unnecessarily. final just means the variable is set once and never get set again.